# Preposition needed: did not survive a certain timepoint

Tags: prepositions, british-english, academic-writing

I have a sentence as follows. This should say that the patients who died during the observation period were excluded from analyses. Should I use a preposition after "survive"? I did a research but found nothing useful.

> Patients, who did not survive at the end of the observation period, were excluded from the analysis.

> Patients, who did not survive beyond the end of the observation period, were excluded from the analysis.

> Patients, who did not survive the end of the observation period, were excluded from the analysis.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to say "Patients who died during the observation period were excluded from the analysis"? Is there some reason to avoid that wording? In any case, you don't need to break out the phrase "who did not survive [beyond] the observation period" with commas.

Comment: Good point. Will use this.

Comment: Your question seems to be off-topic in requiring opinions, and asking for proofreading. However, for the record, I think the second alternative is fine and the others unacceptable. But, how do you know whether my opinion is worth anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patients who did not survive the observation period were excluded from the analysis. (No commas because it's a restrictive appositive, meaning you need this information to understand the sentence.)